# Npm install does not installs secure package though i do npm login followed by npm install commands

Tags: npm, npm-login

Even after logged in using npm login command successfully i get the below error

npm whoami
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! 401 Unauthorized - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/-/whoami

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/bharathkumar/.npm/_logs/2021-09-09T08_42_29_365Z-debug.log

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing contents/remove file .npmrc in the project folder or the user's home folder